# Hide JRXML from customers, if they also use JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Our requirement is to hide *JRXML* from customer, actually we have to install *JasperReports Server* on the customer machine and all the report will be there only.

If they install *iReport* then they will be also able to see our *JRXL* code.

How I can hide *JRXML* files from customers?

Comment: if I may say, the reports will be created upon jrxml , jrxml will not be visible to the customer

Comment: I agree but if they install Ireport then they can see our JRXML.

Comment: why do you need to pass on the uname/pass of jasperserver to the user , won't they be accessing it via thin client ?

Comment: without uname/passwd how they will see the report in Jasperserver?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to hide the JRXML's from customers, keep all the JRXML in different folder of JasperReport sever and then use these JRXML from repository when you create any report in JR server.
    now if you want to hide JRXML files set the permission for this folder.